# Strange behaviour of values from tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

let's suppose the value of ${currentPage} is 5 i.e. we are on the fifth page

there are two links:

```
<a id="idArrow" href="#" data-currentpage="${currentPage-1}" title="${currentPage-1}">backward</a>
<!-- the title displays 4 -->

<a id="idArrow" href="#" data-currentpage="${currentPage+1}" title="${currentPage+1}">forward</a>
<!-- note, the title displays 6, it seems ok-->
```

a script to get a value:

```
$('body').on('click', '#idArrow', function() {          
    console.log("running idArrow");
    var pageNumber = $("#idArrow").data('currentpage');
    console.log('pageNumber '+pageNumber);
...
```

now the most interesting part...
if I press `backward` link then I get

> running idArrow
>
> pageNumber 4

if I press `forward` link then I get the same! how can it be?

> running idArrow
>
> pageNumber 4

Comment: For one thing, you have multiple elements with an id of 'idArrow'.  Ids must be unique per page.

Comment: @Taplar so is it beter to use class for identification?

Comment: You would have to use a class if you want one identifier to map to multiple things.  Otherwise you could make one id 'backArrow', and the other 'forwardArrow' and your delegate selector would just be '#backArrow, #forwardArrow'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the **this** object [provided by jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/events/inside-event-handling-function/) to event handling functions:

```
    var pageNumber = $(this).data('currentpage');
```

Note that you should use unique **id** properties. `$("#idArrow")` refers to the first node with that **id**, and explains the behaviour you describe.

It would therefore be better to give a different selector to the `on` handler, like for instance a class that the elements share:

```
<a class="clsArrow" ... >
```

Code:

```
$('body').on('click', '.clsArrow', function(e) {      
    ...
    var pageNumber = $(this).data('currentpage');
```

Comment: Is `$(e.target)` means `id`?

Comment: No it means "the element you clicked", the e object is passed to the event handler and has many properties about the event, one of which is "target", the element that is the subject of this particular call.

Comment: For the record, this answer is the more correct way of doing this. you got my vote

Comment: Thanks @AdamBuchananSmith ... and @rozero!

Comment: You can use `$(this)` instead of `$(e.target)`. This is more idiomatic.

Comment: @Barmar, you are absolutely right. In this actual case it comes down to the same and is the preferable way to do it. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
<a id="idArrow1" href="#" data-currentpage="${currentPage-1}" title="${currentPage-1}">backward</a>
<!-- the title displays 4 -->

<a id="idArrow2" href="#" data-currentpage="${currentPage+1}" title="${currentPage+1}">forward</a>
<!-- note, the title displays 6, it seems ok-->
```

javascript

```
$('body').on('click', '#idArrow1', function() {          
    console.log("running idArrow1");
    var pageNumber = $("#idArrow1").data('currentpage');
    console.log('pageNumber '+pageNumber);
...

$('body').on('click', '#idArrow2', function() {          
    console.log("running idArrow2");
    var pageNumber = $("#idArrow2").data('currentpage');
    console.log('pageNumber '+pageNumber);
...
```

Your issue is that you have 2 of the same id's make them unique and it should solve your issue